# How to accept any key in python json dictionary?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

Here's a simplified version of the JSON I am working with:

```
{
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library-1": {
        "file": {
          "url": "foobar.com/.../library-1.bin"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "library-2": {
        "application": {
          "url": "barfoo.com/.../library-2.exe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Using json, I can `json.loads()` this file. I need to be able to find the 'url', download it, and save it to a local folder called library. In this case, I'd create two folders within `libraries/`, one called `library-1`, the other `library-2`. Within these folder's would be whatever was downloaded from the url.

The issue, however, is being able to get to the url:

```
my_json = json.loads(...) # get the json

for library in my_json['libraries']:
    file.download(library['file']['url']) # doesn't access ['application']['url']
```

Since the JSON I am using uses a variety of accessors, sometimes 'file', other times 'dll' etc, I can't use one specific dictionary key. How can I use multiple. Would there be a modular way to do this?

Edit: There are numerous accessors, 'file', 'application' and 'dll' are only some examples.

Comment: Your data is currently organized within a list structure. To get to your two urls you need to use my_json["libraries"][0]["librarary-1"]["file"]["url"] and my_json["libraries"][1]"librarary-2"]["application"]["url"]. That is not terribly convenient. Unless the same library can appear twice there is no need to have a list here. If you have control over this you should consider chnaging your JSON structure to just access the libraries directly based on their key

Comment: Also, the distinction between "application" and "file" makes it hard to generalise. Consider standardising this, or even removing the level completely if it only leads to the urls

Comment: @Karl Honestly, Id love to, but this isn't my JSON. I'm simply parsing a JSON from another provider, and cannot change it. Even if I did manually, it constantly is updated with new stuff, making that extremely tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate through each level of the dictionary and download the files if you find a url.

```
urls = []
for library in my_json['libraries']:
    for lib_name, lib_data in library.items():
        for module_name, module_data in lib_data.items():
            url = module_data.get('url')
            if url is not None:
                # create local directory with lib_name
                # download files from url to local directory
                urls.append(url)

# urls = ['foobar.com/.../library-1.bin', 'barfoo.com/.../library-2.exe']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for library in my_json['libraries']:
    if 'file' in library:
        file.download(library['file']['url'])
    elif 'dll' in library:
        file.download(library['dll']['url'])
```

It just sees if your `dict`(created by parsing JSON) has a key named `'file'`. If so, then use `'url'` of the `dict` corresponds to the `'file'` key. If not, try the same with `'dll'` keyword.

**Edit**: If you don't know the key to access the `dict` containing the url, try this.

```py
for library in my_json['libraries']:
    for key in library:
        if 'url' in library['key']:
            file.download(library[key]['url'])
```

This iterates over all the `key`s in your `library`. Then, whichever `key` contains an `'url'`, downloads using that.

Comment: It would be even better if you could [edit] your answer to include a bit on *why* this works.

Comment: I should specify there are more accessors than just 'file' and 'dll'. The json is a mess of different accessors, only where some are 'file' and others are 'dll', so while this might work in the current context, it won't fully be able to cope with the json i'm dealing with

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
for library in my_json['libraries']:
    for value in library.values():
        for url in value.values():
            file.download(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it like this:

```
for library in my_json['libraries']:
    library_data = library.popitem()[1].popitem()[1]
    file.download(library_data['url'])
```